# How to implement the process that consumes data from external Kafka and write into our AWS RDS?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am implementing customer management solution, and receive data from a number of sources, such as gaming platforms, CRM/marketing tools, etc and combine into a standardised data warehouse built in SQL Server. It may receive dta in a number of formats depending on the client, data provider or requirements - flat files on a periodic basis(daily/hourly/etc), vis SNS/SQS streams, vial manual outbound API calls, and via Kafka (along with other sources as required).

For the current implementation, it will be receiving data from other platform(B) via Kafka infrastructure that we have setup in AWS (using AWS MSK). Our implementation need to consume this data into our database staging layer(tables in the exact format of the data messages, pre-transformation to the standardised data platform) on a real time basis so it can be periodically processed and transformed.
Therefore I need to build out a process to “read from external Kafka(Kafka hosted outside of AWS, so won't have Lamda triggers available from MSK), write to db”.

I defined 4 possible approaches-

1. Use a Kafka consumer library
2. Use Kafka connect connector
3. Use a managed Kafka streaming service such as confluent cloud or Amazon MSK
4. Use Amazon Kinesis

As the second option is the best one regarding my case, I tried to utilize this. For testing purpose, I created Kafka cluster on my AWS account and trying to Configure Kafka connect service on AWS ECS.
But it's not clear which connector should I use and how to configure this.

I would be thanksful if someone come up with a quick guide on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options 3 and 4 won't write to RDS. They only start a Kafka cluster, which sounds like you already have.

> not clear which connector should I use and how to configure this

You should use [JDBC Sink](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/sink-connector/overview.html). You can deploy this anywhere into  a Kafka Connect cluster. In AWS, this includes MSK Connect (I think this can connect to self-managed Kafka, but not sure), EC2, ECS, or EKS. It does not run in a Lambda.

Follow [Confluent's documentation on how to use Kafka Connect, in general](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/userguide.html).

> in a number of formats

This connector will only work with a small subset of pre-defined formats, such as JSONSchema, Avro, or Protobuf.

References

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/
- https://rmoff.net/2021/03/12/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink-deep-dive-working-with-primary-keys/

---

You could use Lambda, as well, but that will cause high IO load on your database since each event will open a new database connection.

Comment: I thought that we need to use both source connectors(pulling data from messaging system) and sink connectors(send data to databases, messaging system). JDBC sink is for writing data I think. What other connector should I use for pulling data?

Comment: 1) A Kafka Connect sink automatically consumes (pulls) from Kafka 2) If you download the package for the sink, it also includes the JDBC Source, but I suggest people use Debezium instead, if their database supports it. Otherwise, there are source connectors for SQS or FileSystems; you can use Confluent Hub page or Github to search